# One of my DIV's is always on top

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to layer 2 div's so that the content of one is above another, and the other has an opacity setting to make it translucent. However, no matter which way around I put the HTML for the layers the translucent layer is always above the content. This is the way I would assume to be correct in HTML ordering:

```
<div id="translucent"></div>
<div id="content">...</div>
```

However it doesn't seem to be working - The basic styling I'm using to overlap the layers is here - This works to put one over the other, but the translucent one seems to stay above the other one

```
<style>
    #content
    {
         margin-top:-525px;
    }
    #translucent
    {
         height:525px;
         opacity:0.8;
    }
</style>
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use position and z-indexes? It should work like this:

```
#content {
     margin-top:-525px;
     // positioning something allows you to do more accurate placements
     position: relative;
     // adding a z-index allows you to play with the layers (because... z-axis.)
     z-index: 1;
}
#translucent {
     height:525px;
     opacity:0.8;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 0;
}
```

Basically, the HTML DOM works as following: if it's later in the DOM, it is on top of items earlier in the DOM. Turning the `opacity` down makes the element transparent, but not non-existent. The best way to do this is add `z-index` and a `position`, or just use `display: block;` and `display: none;` To hide one of yours DIVs (but you want the transparency, so I guess thats not an option).

However if you'd use `position: absolute;` you could place the elements in the same place without doing the margin. Then wrap it in another element (say `#wrapper`) and then you can move both boxes at the same time. Add a `width` and `height` of `100%` for both boxes and you can use the wrapper to define both boxes' height and width and the same time! Ahh. CSS Magic.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <div id="translucent"></div>
</div>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#translucent {
    height:525px;
    opacity:0.8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry your initial answer worked, I was just waiting for the 15 minutes to expire so I could accept

Comment: Yeah I took the time to show you a bit more of how layering can be used to your advantage :) Hope it helped.